# Line bundles on curve with nodal singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $C$ be be an irreducible reduced curve over alg closed field $k$ with only one single nodal singularity $x$ and $f:N \to C$ it's normalization with $f^{-1}(x)=\{x_1,x_2\}$ (as set), and an iso everywhere else.

**Question:** How to see **explicity** that the datum of a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ is equivalent to pairs $(\mathcal{N}, \phi)$ where $\mathcal{N}$ a line bundle on $N$ and $\phi: \mathcal{N}_{x_1} \to \mathcal{N}_{x_2}$ iso ( what kind of iso? I guess of $\mathcal{O}_{C,x}$-modules via induced maps $\mathcal{O}_{C,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{N,x_i)}$?

It looks pretty similar to a type of "decent datum" but of course the normalization map is not flat so honest standard descent theory not applies here. So how to elaborate this correspondence in explicit terms? Eg if we start with $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ how does it provide an iso $\phi: (f^*\mathcal{L})_{x_1} \to (f^*\mathcal{L})_{x_2}$  and another way round why a line bundle on $N$ with such iso $\phi$ "descends" to a line bundle on $C$. How to construct it on "clean" formal level?

Note that the picture in context of topological vector bundles is rather clear since the fibers of the pullback of a topol line bundle over $x_1,x_2$ are canonically isomorphic to fiber at $x$ of initial bundle. But I not know how to make the argumentation in realm of algebraic geometry.

Source: [arXiv:0707.4602](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.4602#:%7E:text=We%20study%20the%20theta%20divisor,Noether%20theory%20of%20smooth%20curves.), p 3. I noticed also that it is "considered" as stadard fact, see eg [Geometry of Algebraic Curves, Vol II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-69392-5), p 89, but it also presented there in "hand weavy" manner as more or less plausible thing without deriving it rigorously.

Comment: you may want to have a look at Ferrand's work on pinching [Conducteur, descente et pincement](http://www.numdam.org/articles/10.24033/bsmf.2455/)

Comment: Consider the kernel, as an $\mathcal{O}_C$-module, of the $\mathcal{O}_C$-module homomorphism $\widetilde{\phi}$ from $f_*\mathcal{N}$ to the skyscraper sheaf at $x$, where the homomorphism $\widetilde{\phi}$ is the unique homomorphism from $f_*\mathcal{N}/\mathfrak{m}_xf_*\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{N}_{x_1}\oplus \mathcal{N}_{x_2}$ to the skyscraper sheaf with fiber $\mathcal{N}_{x_2}$ whose first component is $\phi$ and whose second component is the identity.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you, I see, so the main point of confusion was that the part of datum $\phi$ is given not as map between *stalks* $\mathcal{N}_{x_i}$, but their **residues** $\mathcal{N}(x_i):=\mathcal{N}_{x_i} \otimes \kappa(x_i)$, right? Then starting from inv bundle $\mathcal{L}$ it's indeed easy to construct such $\phi: \mathcal{N}(x_1) \to \mathcal{N}(x_2)$: Namely the composition of unit map and proj to residue field $\mathcal{L} \to f_* f^* \mathcal{L} \to \kappa(x)$ factors through

Comment: $f_* f^*\mathcal{L}/\mathfrak{m}_x(f_*f^*\mathcal{L} )= f^*\mathcal{L}(x_1)\oplus f^*\mathcal{L}(x_2)$ so there exist two iso maps $m_i:f^*\mathcal{L}(x_i) \to \kappa(x)$, then we take simply $\phi:= m_2^{-1} \cdot m_1$.